# Problem with the path integral formulation of transition amplitudes in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, path-integral

According to the standard formula for calculating a transition amplitude with fields one has:
\begin{align}
A(i \rightarrow f)&=N \int_{\phi_i}^{\phi_f}\mathcal{D}\phi\,e^{iS}
\\
&=N\prod_n \left[ \int d\phi_n\,e^{ia^4\mathcal{L}_n} \right]e^{ia(L_i+L_f)}
\\
&=N'e^{ia(L_i+L_f)}.
\end{align}
Where I discretized the space-time, so $\mathcal{D}\phi=\prod_n d\phi_n$, the action does not contain derivatives of any kind. $L$ is the lagrangian, $\mathcal{L}$ is the lagrangian density and $a$ is the spacing of the space-time lattice. I think I am wrong with this calculation because to find the normalization factor, just like in quantum mechanics where we integrate the amplitude over all possible final positions, I functional-integrate it over final configurations and force it to be 1. Then we have:
\begin{equation}
N'=\left[ \int \mathcal{D}\phi_f\,e^{ia(L_i+L_f)} \right]^{-1},
\end{equation}
which annihilates the $e^{iaL_i}$ contribution. This is interpreted as the fact that the transition amplitude does not depend on the initial state, which is wrong. Where am I wrong in this sketch of calculation?

Comment: My lagrangian does not involve derivatives of any kind, I will edit my post so it will be clear. Do you mean that without time derivative and these cross terms, the transition amplitude does not depend on the initial state?

Comment: Well if your Lagrangian does not have any derivatives of any kind, it very likely does not describe any dynamics. Another thing to be checked "it seems to me that the normalization factor $N$..." says very little on how you come to $N´$, please expand

Comment: I would have thought the normalization condition would be something like, the integral over all possible final states of the squared transition amplitudes should be 1. (Eg: the probability should be 1 that the system ends up in one of the possible final states). There should also be an overall ambiguity in the phase, which your normalization condition does not have.

Comment: @ohneVal I've edited my question so my reasoning is clearer.

Comment: @Andrew I think that in quantum mechanics, one does not take the square of the amplitude, because the probability does not have any phase. For example for a free particle in QM, the phase depends on $x$ and $t$. Then if you take the probability to be 1 instead of the amplitude, your integration just yields the volume of the final position space and not the known factor.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux The typical normalization condition for a wavefunction is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx |\psi(x)|^2=1$ (probability that a particle is "somewhere" sums to one). This does mean that the wavefunction is only defined up to an overall phase. (see, eg, these notes by Richard Fitzpatrick: http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/qmech/Quantum/node34.html)

Comment: @Andrew I agree with you for a wavefunction, but what I work with is not a wavefunction but a transition amplitude, and in this case, one does not take the modulus squared of the amplitude (see (2.5) and (2.6) here https://indico.cern.ch/event/206621/attachments/317310/442802/LecturesMorelia_OC.pdf , Quantum Mechanical Path Integrals: from Transition
Amplitudes to Worldline Formalism, Olindo Corradini)

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux The sum of the probabilities for every final state *must* sum to 1, and you can derive a normalization condition from this. But the notes you linked to discuss the transition amplitude, and for that the normalization condition is fixed by the requirement that the amplitude be $\delta(x-x')$ at $t=0$ (eq 2.2), and that as a function of time the amplitude has a unitary evolution (2.1). If you satisfy these conditions, you will guarantee that the probability of being in one of the final states sums to 1. What normalization condition are you using to compute $N'$?

Comment: The normalization condition I use is $\int \mathcal{D} \phi_f\,A(i \rightarrow f)=1$. I don't understand your reasoning because if one takes for example $\delta(x-x')$ as (2.2) at $t=0$ in the document I linked, the amplitude satisfies $\int dx'\,K(x,x';t)=1$ but the probability is $|\delta(x-x')|^2$, which gives $\int dx'\,|K(x,x';t)|^2=\delta(0)$.